# Ubuntu 20.04 Purple Boot Screen with "Ubuntu 20.04" and White and Orange dots

Tags: bootloader

I powered on my computer when I was getting ready to use it, and as soon as I turn my monitor on, I had a loading purple screen that says "Ubuntu 20.04" and it has a White and Orange dots, but still boots up, my computer usually boots up with my computer brand name with a spinning wheel

Does anybody know why the boot screen changed?

Disclaimer: If this doesn't make sense, please let me know, and I will rephrase it to make it understandable ^_^

Comment: Status please...

Comment: This is a good information, now my computer brand name with the spinning wheel is back, thank you so much heynnema ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plymouth greeting screen has changed. Do...

`ls -al /etc/alternatives/*.plymouth`

and you should see this...

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 May 12  2020 default.plymouth -> /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Apr 21  2019 text.plymouth -> /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth
```

Your default.plymouth probably looks different.

See `man update-alternatives` for detailed help.

Use the following command to fix it...

`sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`

Choose the bgrt item.

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

`reboot`